# CXF 3.1.6 file upload, attachment datahandler input stream is null

Tags: java, null, cxf, inputstream

I'm using cxf and working on the file upload where i'm receiving the file content as an Attachment. Upon debug i see the file payload being present in the dataHandler object of the attachment, but when i do a inputStream, content is null.

Code Snippet:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
        MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("/{catalogId}/file")
public CatalogResponse addFile(@Context HttpHeaders headers,
        @PathParam("catalogId") String catalogId, @Multipart(value = "requestFile")Attachment file,
        boolean autoLaunch) {
    CatalogResponse res;
    try {
        InputStream is = file.getDataHandler().getInputStream();
        buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        [enter image description here][1]while ((read = inputStream.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                  buffer.write(data, 0, read);
                }
        buffer.flush();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
     //handle the exception
    }
```

Please find the data below. I see the input stream is marked as '**closed**' which is causing the issue, i guess.